# Drawbacks in registering receivers in both the activity and service?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, localbroadcastmanager

The scenario is like this: I have an activity and a service. There are a few things that need to be sent between both:

- the activity can query the service to see if running
- the activity can query the service for variable value
- the activity can ask the service to perform action (run a method of it)
- the service can send response to the activity on action
- the service can respond back to activity on activity call

Since this looks more as a two-way communication, I am thinking of using `LocalBroadcastManager` and have something like:

```
public class MyActivity extents Activity{

   private void receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
      onReceive(){
        //Handle Message from Service
      }
  }

  onResume -> LocalBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(receiver);
  onPause  -> LocalBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(); 
}
```

and for service

```
public class MyService extents Service{

   private void receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
      onReceive(){
        //Handle Message from Activity
      }
  }

  onStart-> LocalBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(receiver);
  onDestroy-> LocalBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(); 
}
```

This would allow to avoid binding or other methods of communication between app components but in the same time allows both to sent intents and listen for observers. Are there any drawbacks on this method?

Comment: What sort of drawbacks?

Comment: Mostly, on what I read, the broadcast receiver is used for one way talk, for instance, from Service->Activity and for Activity->Service usually there's `bind`. So I thought that maybe there are some drawbacks to this or it's not recommended by some reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be.

This is the recommended way of cross-component communication within an Android app. You're doing exactly what Google recommends, with local broadcasts instead of global broadcasts.

In a comment, you mentioned that binding a Service is usually what to do for Activity->Service communication. You don't need to use this in most cases. Binding a Service is kind of annoying, since it isn't instant and you need to use a listener to store a reference to the Binder. Broadcasts, in comparison, are relatively simple.

Comment: Thank you for your time. One thing that comes in mind is what happens with the registered broadcast receiver if the service gets killed by OS? This means that `onDestroy` isn't called...

Comment: Then it leaks. It's not too big a deal. The same issue occurs if you use a Binder (`onServiceDisconnected()` won't be called).

Comment: Any other way that works and allows me to avoid leaks? But I guess this is an issue for multiple things, like any other sort of listeners that are registered but don't get a chance to get unregistered.

Comment: Make it a foreground Service and it's unlikely to be killed. Android fragmentation is a big issue in development and you'll never be able to account for everything.

Comment: It's already a foreground service. Another way I think of could be of starting the service with a new intent with the params I want.. this should trigger `onStartCommand` and so the Activity could send message to Service in this way. However it feels too complex. The activity is safer as it unregisters within `onPause`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your activity should just bind to the service to get a Binder instance that you can use to access service methods.  The service can send local broadcasts that the Activity can observe with Broadcast Receivers.  My recent preference is have the service methods return LiveData instances that can be observed instead.  LiveData objects are lifecycle aware so any observers will know to clean up after themselves.

Comment: This is pretty awesome, however, I don't want to go using the new arch components.

Comment: You can rely on the broadcast receivers in the Activity then to watch for state changes in the service then use services.  Also, binding services allows the Activity to send messages the bound service via method calls and also prevents that service from being killed by the OS.